# KIF Integration tests: how to click subview of table row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, integration-testing

I have a table view whose rows each contain a "favorite" button. I'd like to click these in an integration test, but I don't see a good way to do it.

I'm looking for something like a combination of `stepToTapRowInTableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:atIndexPath:` and `stepToTapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:`.

Something that I would probably call `stepToTapSubviewWithAccessibilityLabel:ofRowInTableViewWithAccessibilityLabel:atIndexPath:`.

I see there is a step to tap a specific point, but it seems rather brittle. Any ideas?